# xcodebuild via jenkins and ssh fail with "Your session has expired. Please log in."

Tags: xcode, jenkins

When using Jenkins and/or ssh to invoke xcodebuild, I keep encountering the following error:

```
Error Domain=DVTPortalServiceErrorDomain Code=1100 "Your session has expired. Please log in."
```

Logging in to the account and running my build locally works fine; it's only via Jenkins or ssh from another account/machine where it fails. Prior to invoking xcodebuild, I unlock the keychain, and confirmed that these commands have executed successfully:

```
/usr/bin/security lock-keychain ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain
/usr/bin/security unlock-keychain -p 'mypwd' ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain
/usr/bin/security set-keychain-settings -t 9600 ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain
```

I have tried Apple support, who said it must be a bug. I submitted a bug report, no response.

Has anyone else had this problem and resolved it?